# comparing multiple columns at once with App Scripts

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, google-apps-script, javascript-objects

I need some help determining the most efficient way to compare combinations of columns in one row a sheet with another.

I have two tables, which both have four columns: State, Area, City & Location.

PINPOINT table - this table has a unique combination of values

FEED table - this table has a recurring combination of values, as well as the KEY value from the PINPOINT Table.

What i want is a code that says

"If a row from column CL in the FEED sheet contains the Key Value from column K in the PINPOINT sheet,

...but columns CN to CQ that FEED sheet row doesn't have the same values as column A-D in the PINPOINT table...

update column CN to CQ the FEED sheet with the same combination of values as A-D in the PINPOINT table."

I pasted the latest code i have below, as well as the images. It gives me an array saying the arrays are "undefined." I just started learning code, so I'm happy to rewrite this if someone proposes a solution.

In any case, any insight into how i should write this will be quite helpful.

```
var Data = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); // DATA spreadsheet

  var PinpointDataSheet = Data.getSheetByName("The Pinpoints") // DATA "Pinpoint" sheet
  var PinpointAllValues = PinpointDataSheet.getRange(2, 1, PinpointDataSheet.getLastRow()-1,PinpointDataSheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();


  var FeedDataSheet = Data.getSheetByName("The Feed_Raw") // DATA "Feed" sheet
  var FeedAllValues = FeedDataSheet.getRange(2, 1, FeedDataSheet.getLastRow()-1,FeedDataSheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();

  var PinpointStateObj = {}; // Object for "Locale" values
  var PinpointAreaObj = {}; // Object for "Locale" values
  var PinpointCityObj = {}; // Object for "Locale" values
  var PinpointSpotObj = {}; // Object for "Locale" values

  for(var P = PinpointAllValues.length-1;P>=0;P--) // put Pinpoint values in array..

  {
    PinpointStateObj[PinpointAllValues[P][0]] = PinpointAllValues[P][10]; 
    PinpointAreaObj[PinpointAllValues[P][1]] = PinpointAllValues[P][10]; 
    PinpointCityObj[PinpointAllValues[P][2]] = PinpointAllValues[P][10];
    PinpointSpotObj[PinpointAllValues[P][3]] = PinpointAllValues[P][10]; 
  }

  for(var F = FeedAllValues.length-1;F>=0;F--) // for each row in the "Feed" sheet...
  { 
   var Feed_GeotagKey = FeedAllValues[F][90]; // Pinpoint Key values in Feed sheet
    {
      // If Pinpoint array dont match feed values
      if ((PinpointStateObj[Feed_GeotagKey] != FeedAllValues[F][95]) || (PinpointAreaObj[Feed_GeotagKey] != FeedAllValues[F][96]) 
        || (PinpointCityObj[Feed_GeotagKey] != FeedAllValues[F][97]) || (PinpointSpotObj[Feed_GeotagKey] != FeedAllValues[F][97]))
        {
        FeedAllValues[F][95] = PinpointAllValues[P][0]; // ...Change FYI Category Name in FYI Topic Sheet 
        FeedAllValues[F][96] = PinpointAllValues[P][1];
        FeedAllValues[F][97] = PinpointAllValues[P][2];
        FeedAllValues[F][98] = PinpointAllValues[P][3];

      }
    }
  }
```

[Geotag Sheet - unique values "Dark column"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UggnZ.png)
[Feed Sheet - recurring values - "Highlighted column"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ywjgb.png)

Answer (score 0):

1. You have a typing mistake - please change

`PinpointStateObj[PinpointtAllValues[P][0]] = PinpointAllValues[P][10];`

to

`PinpointStateObj[PinpointAllValues[P][0]] = PinpointAllValues[P][10];`

2. Your `if` statement contains `(PinpointHoodObj[Feed_GeotagKey] != FeedAllValues[F][97])`, but you do not have an array called `inpointHoodObj` - I assume you mean `PinpointCityObj`
3. As for the rest of your code, it is hard to say if it works as intended without seeing your spreadsheet (what are the values in e.g. `PinpointAllValues[P][10]` or `FeedAllValues[F][95]`?) and the rest of your code (where you assign the correctly sorted values to your range in FEED, but as a general advice:

Use [indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf). It is a Javascript method that allows you to BOTH find out either a key is contained in an array at all AND retrieve its position within the array.

Sample:

```
...
//check either PinpointStateObj[Feed_GeotagKey] is contained in row FeedAllValues[F]
if(FeedAllValues[F].indexOf(PinpointStateObj[Feed_GeotagKey])!=-1){
//if the key value is contained in the row - find its position (column)
  var columnNumber=FeedAllValues[F].indexOf(PinpointStateObj[Feed_GeotagKey])+1;
  //implement a comparison either the column where the key value is contained corresponds to the desired one
  ...
  }
...
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestions. I was trying to reformat my code to make it easier to understand. I'll make those changes and let you know. I also added images of my spreadsheet in the original post to help clarify my problem.

Comment: hey sorry for the delayed response. I had a little bit of difficulty figuring it out, so i went in a different direction. I made a post about it here [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59870660/how-can-i-compare-multiple-google-sheet-values-using-google-apps-script]